# calling a library function of arbitrary name

Tags: clojure

say there's a library `l`, which has two functions (`a` and `b`).

Calling both functions and merging the results into a vector could be done like this:

```
(concat (l/a) (l/b))
```

Is there a way to make this more generic? I tried something like this, but it threw an exception:

```
(apply concat (map #(l/%)  ['a 'b]))
```

of course, this would work:

```
(apply concat [l/a l/b])
```

Comment: I assume you mean _namespace_ instead of _library_?

Comment: concat never returns a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Calling both functions and merging the results into a vector could be done like this:
>   (concat (l/a) (l/b))

No, you will not get a vector. And you will only get a sequence if those functions return sequences. Otherwise, definitely not, you will get a runtime exception with this code and your assumption.

It sounds like you have a bunch of functions and you want to concatenate the results of them all together? There is no need to quote them, just make a sequence of the functions:

`[l/a l/b l/c ...]`

And use `apply` with `concat` as you already are, or use `reduce` to accumulate values.

Call `vec` on the result if you need it to be a vector rather than a sequence.

Your other solutions are definitely making your code much much more complex, unnecessary, and difficult to read. (also, you almost never need to quote vars as you are doing)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a general way of invoking a function inside a namespace. You can construct a symbol and dereference it to find the functions, then combine the results using `mapcat` e.g.

```
(mapcat #((find-var (symbol "l" %))) ["a" "b"])
```

alternatively you could first find the namespace and use `ns-resolve` to find the vars e.g.

```
(let [ns (find-ns 'l)]
   (mapcat #((ns-resolve ns %)) ['a 'b]))
```